# change default charset of JVM to UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding

My default charset of JVM is windows-1252. that's what i get when I run this code :

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

I want to change it to UTF-8. How to do it in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you mean for your console output. If yes then Go to Run Configuration -> Common and select from the encoding drop down as UTF-8. Here is the picture to help you:

[image]